# How can I create an array of indexes of props.children elements of a component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel, react-props

I'm trying to build a carousel app where you can put the carousel items as children of the carousel component.

```
   return (
    <div className="carousel-container" style={{width: containerWidth}}>
    <button className="button-left" >L</button>
    <button className="button-right" >R</button>
    <div className="carousel-slider" style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "row",
         flexWrap: "none",
      overflow: "scroll",
     alignItems: "center",
    height: props.height, 
    width: "100%", 
    }}>
        {props.children}
    </div>
    </div>
)
```

I want to be able to scroll this carousel to the selected child. The way I figure I should do it is by having the button-left and button-right elements scroll to the index of the next/previous child. However, I have no way of getting the indexes of children to tell the app to scroll to a certain child.

Does anyone know a way for me to get the indexes of the props.children of "carousel-slider", put them in an array, then scroll to the respective child on the press of the left/right buttons? The children are HTML emenets, like divs or imges.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-goodall-usspz?file=/src/App.js

P.S. I know there are really cool carousel addons out there. I'm doing this to get better at React.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! *"Codesandbox: [link]"*  The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: In addition to the resources linked by @T.J.Crowder, you might also want to have a look at the ["*How do I create a React Stack Snippet with JSX support?*" mini-guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/14201528)

Comment: Thank you for the help guys. I'll check out the resources you linked.  I think the code snippet in the OP can be considered a reprex, I only added the codesandbox if anyone wanted to play around with the code themselves. That react strack snippet trick seems very useful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`React.Children.toArray`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrentoarray) to turn the `children` prop into an array of children. From the docs:

> Returns the `children` opaque data structure as a flat array with keys assigned to each child. Useful if you want to manipulate collections of children in your render methods, especially if you want to reorder or `slice` `this.props.children` before passing it down.

Once you have an array, you can use indexing into the array.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I'll try it out and report back.

Comment: This worked indeed, though after some fidgeting I realized that my approach was unnecessarily convoluted and scrapped the project. I decided to build a new carousel using a different approach. Thanks for the help!